# How to get total amount of RAM in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, winforms, ram

I need to get a total amount of RAM on Windows Form load. I tried to get it like this:

```
#include <windows.h>

Form1(void)
{
   MEMORYSTATUSEX statex;
   statex.dwLength = sizeof(statex);
   GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&statex);
   unsigned long long RAM_GB = statex.ullTotalPhys / 1024ll / 1024ll / 1024ll;
}
```

Here I get RAM_GB = 23, but my computer has 32GB of RAM. How does this function work? Why does it show me less memory than my computer actually has?

Comment: ...wait a sec. The question you link is C# but you want to use C++, right?

Comment: anyhow you should include your errors in the question

Comment: @Perotto why don't you show the C++ code you have tried? Then someone can tell you what is wrong with it. Showing C# code isn't going to help anyone help you

Comment: What is the value of statex.ullTotalPhys ?

Comment: statex.ullTotalPhys 25714225152 unsigned __int64

Comment: The function only reports the amount of *usable* RAM, always less than the installed RAM.  You'll lose some when the system copies the BIOS from ROM into RAM, the OS cannot see that back.  Not that much less however, conceivably it could be the video driver hacking off that much for its shared memory.  That's a guess.  Use the System::Management namespace to run WMI queries.

Comment: is the pc you run the code on 32 bit or 64 bit?